# how to access to the X coordinate only in C#?

Tags: c#, console

this below code gives me outuput like this {X=387.929, Y=555.55} cane anyone suggest mt how to access only X coordinate in C#

```
        PdfTextFind[] results = null;
        foreach (PdfPageBase page in doc.Pages)
        {
            results = page.FindText("Earnest").Finds;
            foreach (PdfTextFind text in results)
            {
                PointF p = text.Position;
                Console.WriteLine(p);
            }
        }`
```

Comment: `float x = text.Position.X;`

Comment: it worked thanks sir

Answer (score 0):

PointF is a simple struct that contains two floats: X and Y. (And some methods, operators, and so on) So simply call

```
Console.WriteLine(p.X);
```